# Creating a json array in python from bunch of strings

Tags: python, json, mapping

In this script I'm parsing an html page using bs4

```
with urlopen('https://ahmia.fi/search/?q=' + searchString) as webpage:
    rawResaults = webpage.read().decode()

# Parsing the webpage to html using BeautifulSoup
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(rawResaults, features="lxml")
```

then looping through each <li> element to get the value of element that is located inside that list item

```
for res in parsed_html.body.find_all_next('li', attrs={'class': 'result'}):
    i = i + 1

    titel = str(res.find('a').text)
    description = str(res.find('p').text)
    description = description.strip()
    description = description.replace("<p>","")
    description = description.replace("<br>","")
    link = str(res.find('cite').text)
    lastCheckd = str(res.find('span').text)
```

What I want to do is combine all these strings into a JSON array which then will be sent to the frontend that will map through the JSON to create new components 'link' that take the props (titel,decription,link,lastChecked)

```
{/* {link ? (
            link.map((lnk) => (
              <Links
              
                key={lnk._id}
                titel={lnk.titel}
                link={lnk.link}
                description={lnk.description}
                status={lnk.status}
              />
            ))
          ) : (
            <Nolink />
          )} */}
```

Here is what I've tried so far (I can't map through the result )

```
#How I declared 'dictz' 
 dictz = {}
    #this part is inside the loop
    dictz["link"+str(i)]={
        "titel": titel.strip(),
        "description": (description[:75] + '..') if len(description) > 75 else description ,
        "link": link.strip(),
        "lastCheckd": lastCheckd.strip(),
        "status": "unknown"
        }
   

# outside the loop
serialized_json = json.dumps(dictz)
```

An example result :

```js
{
  "link1": {
    "titel": "hello, anon.",
    "description": "hello, anon - Uncensored Onion ",
    "link": "LINK",
    "lastCheckd": "1, 3 ago",
    "status": "unknown"
  },
  "link2": {
    "titel": "Hello",
    "description": "No description provided",
    "link": "LINK",
    "lastCheckd": "2, 1 ago",
    "status": "unknown"
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get with your code?

Comment: `.text` doesn't return HTML tags, you shouldn't need those `.replace()` calls.

Comment: `link.map()` requires `link` to be an array, not an object. That means that in Python you should create a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: @barmar i know that .text doesn't return HTML tags but in this case i did find some of them in the output i'm not sur why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary. Instead of putting `linkN` in the dictionary keys, it should be in the `_id` key of the nested dictionaries.

```
dictz = []
...
dictz.append({
        "_id": "link"+str(i),
        "titel": titel.strip(),
        "description": (description[:75] + '..') if len(description) > 75 else description ,
        "link": link.strip(),
        "lastCheckd": lastCheckd.strip(),
        "status": "unknown"
    })
```